# Cannot get 301 to work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am working on some redirections and I can't get them to work. I am trying to redirect this page `http://www.sparkpe.org/blog/category/spark-blog/?attachment_id=1073` to the homepage.

I tired several solutions like,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^attachment_id=1073$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /summit/summit-presentations/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^attachment_id=1073$
RewriteRule ^blog/category/spark-blog/(.*)$ http://www.sparkpe.org/blog/? [R=301,L]
```

and also I tried removing `$` and  `?` but none of these solutions seem to be working. What could the problem be?

Comment: Have you made sure rewriting is on?  I just tried the first rule on my localhost and it's working. Anyway you can figure out what's going on by raising the log level for the rewrite module, as explained here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: yep it is on.....ok will check that resource. Thank you so much for now!